# LaTeX Equations Not Rendered on Webpage

Tags: r, latex, markdown, knitr

When I go to a webpage, such as this [page of examples](http://www.calvin.edu/~rpruim/courses/m343/F12/RStudio/LatexExamples.html), none of the LaTeX code is being rendered in any of the browsers I try. However, on the same computer, if I create a simple R Markdown file in RStudio and I click Knit HTML, the preview in the RStudio: Preview HTML window shows LaTeX commands being rendered correctly. If I then open the HTML file which was created in any web browser, the LaTeX commands are not rendered. I see ( \log_2(x) ) instead. What must be done to render it in an internet browser ? I have tried three computers and the problem happens on each of them.

```
other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.5 formatR_1.0    stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: The author of the page needs to re-compile the page using the latest versions of knitr and markdown on CRAN. The reason for the failure is exactly what @BeDutra described below.

Comment: @Yihui It's also worth noting that using Knit HTML button won't work in older versions of RStudio, even if the updated packages are installed. It's possible, of course, to use the `knit` and `markdownToHTML` commands in the console window, after loading **knitr** and **markdown**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript path to mathjax seems to be wrong:

```
<!-- MathJax scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/2.0-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

If I try to download the MathJax.js file, my browser tells me the file cannot be found. So your path is wrong, or you need to change the read permissions.

See http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html